# Expressing as 1's complement

Tags: computer-science, binary

I have the problem:

```
Express ( -43) as a word-length 1’s complement number
```

43 is in decimal. I understand how to convert to Hexadecimal and take the 2's compliment, but am confused on what exactly I have to do to get the desired answer here. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

$43$ in binary is $101011$.  I think word-length is $16$-bits, so we pad out and say that $43$ is actually $00000000000000101011$.  The first bit is not part of the number; this is the sign bit, by switching it to $1$, we make the number negative.  However, with $1$'s complement, you need to toggle all the other bits when making it negative.  So to make it negative, just toggle all bits:  $-43$ is $11111111111111010100$.